# Deadlock when calling task_done() as the task has been pulled by a new thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I am giving Python (3.4) a try with multithreading and have a question on the following code.

The code works well when I have a a greater amount of work than `NUM_WORKER_THREADS`; however once the queue shrinks to less than the `NUM_WORKER_THREADS` count, new iterations can take the same item due to the time between `items.get()` and the `task_done` call.This results in a deadlock when calling `task_done`.

What is the correct way to handle this?

```
import time
import threading

from queue import Queue
NUM_WORKER_THREADS = 8

def worker():
    try:
        while items.qsize() > 0:
            print("{} items left to process".format(items.qsize())) 
            item = items.get()                
            print("Processing {}".format(item))   
            itemrec = getItemRecord(item) # external call to webservice ~3 second response.               
            items.task_done()

    except Exception as inst:
        print("---------------EXCEPTION OCCURRED----------------")
        print(type(inst))
        print(inst.args)
        print(inst)


# start counter to monitor performance
start = time.perf_counter()

items = Queue()
# get the items we need to work on for allocations
searchResults = getSearchResults() # external call to webservice

# add results of search to a collection
for itemid in searchResults:
    if itemid['recordtype'] == 'inventoryitem':
        items.put(itemid['id'])

for i in range(NUM_WORKER_THREADS):
    try:
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
    except Exception as inst:
        print("---------------EXCEPTION OCCURRED----------------")
        print(type(inst))
        print(inst.args)
        print(inst)            

items.join()

# print end of execution performance counter 
print('time:', time.perf_counter() - start)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a sentinel to tell the workers to shut down when there are no more work items to process, rather than relying on the `Queue` size, which is susceptible to race conditions:

```
import time
import threading

from queue import Queue
NUM_WORKER_THREADS = 8

def worker():
    for item in iter(items.get, None):
        try:
            print("{} items left to process".format(items.qsize())) 
            print("Processing {}".format(item))   
        except Exception as inst:
            print("---------------EXCEPTION OCCURRED----------------")
            print(type(inst))
            print(inst.args)
            print(inst)
        finally:
            items.task_done()
    print("Got sentinel, shut down")
    items.task_done()

# start counter to monitor performance
start = time.perf_counter()

items = Queue()
# get the items we need to work on for allocations
searchResults = getSearchResults() # external call to webservice

# add results of search to a collection
for itemid in searchResults:
    if itemid['recordtype'] == 'inventoryitem':
        items.put(itemid['id'])

for _ in range(NUM_WORKER_THREADS):
   items.put(None) # Load a sentinel for each worker thread

for i in range(NUM_WORKER_THREADS):
    try:
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
    except Exception as inst:
        print("---------------EXCEPTION OCCURRED----------------")
        print(type(inst))
        print(inst.args)
        print(inst)            

items.join()

# print end of execution performance counter 
print('time:', time.perf_counter() - start)
```

Also note that you can use the built-in thread pool provided by Python ([`multiprocessing.dummy.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy)) to do this more elegantly:

```
import time
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool  # Thread Pool

NUM_WORKER_THREADS = 8

def worker(item):
    try:
        print("Processing {}".format(item))   
        itemrec = getItemRecord(item) # external call to webservice ~3 second response.               
    except Exception as inst:
        print("---------------EXCEPTION OCCURRED----------------")
        print(type(inst))
        print(inst.args)
        print(inst)

# start counter to monitor performance
start = time.perf_counter()

# get the items we need to work on for allocations
searchResults = getSearchResults() # external call to webservice
pool = Pool(NUM_WORKER_THREADS)
pool.map(worker, [item['id'] for item in searchResults 
                    if item['recordtype'] == 'inventoryitem'])
pool.close()
pool.join()


# print end of execution performance counter 
print('time:', time.perf_counter() - start)
```